# Getting error on updating datatable with json returned from ajax servlet call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting this eror when I try to load my table using datatable... DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Here is my jquery call to the servlet

```js
function fetchClients(id){
 
 $('document').ready(function(){
  $('#example').dataTable({
   "processing":true,
   "serverSide":true,
   "ajax":{
    "url":"/DashBoard/FetchClients",
    "dataType":"json",
    "data": {alertId: id},
    "type":"POST"
    },
    "columns":[
     {"data": "obj.clientName"},
     {"data": "obj.AliasName"},
     {"data": "obj.Status"},
     {"data": "obj.Time"},
     {"data": "obj.Date"}
    ]
   });
 });
}
```

```js
while(rs.next()){
                obj1=new JSONObject();
                obj1.put("clientId",rs.getString("ClientID"));
                obj1.put("clientName",rs.getString("ClientName"));
                obj1.put("AliasName",rs.getString("AliasName"));
                obj1.put("Status", rs.getString("Status"));
                Timestamp tem=rs.getTimestamp("Date");
                SimpleDateFormat s1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                Date d1=s1.parse(tem+"");
                int hour=d1.getHours();
                int min=d1.getMinutes();
                if(hour==0){
                    obj1.put("Time", hour+":"+min+"PM");
                }
                else if(hour>=13)
                {
                    obj1.put("Time", (hour-12)+":"+min+"PM");
                }
                else
                    obj1.put("Time", hour+":"+min+"AM");
                s1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                obj1.put("Date", s1.format(d1)+"");
                obj.put(obj1);
            }
                json.put("obj", obj);
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
            out.print(json);
            out.close();
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

</table>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not initialising the datatable somewhere else?

Comment: Ya.. But thats in another servlet and both are different requests.. The method fetchClients will be called only on clicking certain button.. The another servlet dynamically searches database and adds  a button. Both uses same database but different tables..

Comment: no servlet is not problem here.. the problem is you are initialising datatable on click of button more than once.
Can you brief me about scenario/requirement.

Comment: Whenever the user clicks the button obviously the jquery will be called.. Which obviously intialize the table i think??!! How to avoid this?? I need to call the url whenever the button is pressed, the table should be updated based on the json returned from the request

Comment: then destroy the old table first. Datatable plugin straightly says do not (can't) initialise same table more than once.

Comment: I destroyed but now no result inside table... Its simply displaying processing columns inside it. Is it I need to put table headers or anything inside the html tablee?

Comment: did you try below code?

Comment: Ya I tried with that code too..

Comment: Hi, Its working now.. As the json is array of objects I modified name of json array object as aaData and in ajax columns to aoColumns and for the columns data mData.. It is working now.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```js
var table; // global variable, also can skip this statement
function fetchClients(id){
if(table){ table.destroy(); } //destroy if already initialised
  table = $('#example').dataTable({
   "processing":true,
   "serverSide":true,
   "ajax":{
    "url":"/DashBoard/FetchClients",
    "dataType":"json",
    "data": {alertId: id},
    "type":"POST"
    },
    "columns":[
     {"data": "obj.clientName"},
     {"data": "obj.AliasName"},
     {"data": "obj.Status"},
     {"data": "obj.Time"},
     {"data": "obj.Date"}
    ]
 });
}
```

Comment: check in console If you are getting the response

Comment: where else do you have the datatable's javascript  code that deals with datatable, can you paste it

Comment: how?? I am beginner with jquer ajax datatable things

Comment: you are showing table only on button click, you sure? first time its nothing there right? only when you click on button it should display table?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle so that I can see the console errors and can see the other code too

Comment: Ya.. on clicking that button only the table will get displayed.. but there after it should remain there on the screen and should be updated.. when i click another button the table will be updated based on the query

Answer (score 0):

Its working now.. As the json is array of objects I modified name of json array object as aaData and in ajax columns to aoColumns and for the columns data mData.. It is working now.. Thanks a lot